# How to remove the trailing slash of Symfony2 root domain route

Tags: symfony, mod-rewrite

I've found lots of information on how to deal with trailing slashes of routes like:

`http://app1.local/activity/`

`http://app1.local/reports/`

from within Symfony2 but none on how to deal with the root one:

`http://app1.local/`

If I do `@Route("", name="treasure_forge_home_overview")` it works but still adds the trailing "/".

I understand that having "/" might be mandatory for the router to work, but I also refuse to believe that it looks nice to all of you and that there's no solution to this. Are the default mod_rewrite rules adding it? I'm not very good with rewrite rules.

I'd prefer an **internal** Symfony2 solution instead of a mod_rewite one, but I'll have to take any.

Many thanks!

P.S. Symfony 2.4.1

Sample from current routing.yml:

```
treasure_forge_core:
    resource: "@TreasureForgeCoreBundle/Controller"
    type: annotation
    prefix: /
```

In my CoreController:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="treasure_forge_home_overview")
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function overviewAction(){}
```

and

```
/**
 * @Route("/activity", name="treasure_forge_home_activity")
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function activityAction(){}
```

Contents of .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I often leave the trailing slash out of my route annotation and my route then only works without trailing slash. Have you perhaps put one in `routing.yml`?

Comment: You're right, I had a pointer to annotation route with `prefix: /` in routing.yml but when I tried `prefix: ` and `prefix: ""` it had no effect. I get the impression that the default rewrite rules add it. How to change that I wonder...

Comment: Where do you specify `/activity/` or `/reports/`?

Comment: Could you please update your question displaying `routing.yml` and an outtake of your controller (or the full controller depending on the relevance) with at least one action and the class declaration?

Comment: What about `class CoreController` any `@Route` annotations there?

Comment: No, plain `class MainController extends Controller`

Comment: Curious, and if you try without trailing slash you get a 404?

Comment: No, it just puts the training slash back on and returns the home page as it should.